# How to run code based on file name in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a folder at the moment containing various files that I need to run some code on and convert into a csv. I'm trying to see if there is a way to check the name of the file in the folder and then execute the respective code. I have tried:

```
for xlsb_file in pathlib.Path('Directory Path').glob('Filename*.xlsb'):
RUN CODE
convert dataset into a csv
```

For some reason this code seems to execute without any error but no csv file is outputted. Ideally what I would like is when I run the code, for the code to detect the filename, run the respective code and then spit out a csv.

Is there anyway to do this? All help is appreciated!

Comment: Could a solution be to supply the directory name via command line argument?

Comment: Of course you *can* analyze the file names and take appropriate action.  What’s your question about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
import os

def convert_to_csv(filename):
    """this function converts and save a csv version of the file"""

def convert_this_file(filename):
    """this functions checks if a file should be converted"""
    return filename.endswith('.xlsb')

for root, folders, files in os.walk('Directory Path'):
    for file in files:
        filename = os.path.join(root, file)
        if convert_this_file(filename):
            convert_to_csv(filename)
    break
```

Remove the 'break' if you want the code scan sub directories recursively